# Is converge pointwise with this property implies uniform convergence?

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in (\mathbb C^{[a,b]})^{\mathbb N}$ which validates the property :

$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists\delta>0, \forall x,y\in[a,b], |x-y|\le\delta \implies \forall n\in \mathbb N, |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le \varepsilon$

If $(f_n)_n$ converge pointwise, will $(f_n)_n$ converge uniformly ?

It seems to be working. Though I don't know how to begin.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Equicontinuity_and_uniform_convergence

Comment: I had never heard of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem. Though, It doesn't seem to help because we need the uniform for $(f_n)$ not for a subsequence. But $(f_n)$ may be continuous.

Comment: The sentence right after the one you probably read: "In view of Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, a sequence in C(X) converges uniformly if and only if it is equicontinuous and converges pointwise." (same wiki page)

Comment: @BrunoB Oh yes, I see ! Thanks, I didn't notice it !

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you !

Comment: @AndrésCarcel Yes It did answer my question ! I didn't know that the prove could be extend on a compact metric spaces though the article in comment shows it too. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome! And sorry for my mistake :)

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for having copied-pasted the sentence of Wikipedia I wanted to show. Now I am wondering how I could have justified it and dispelled the OP's doubts. Of course the proof of the duplicate is simpler and sufficient, but how could we alternatively invoke Ascoli? Is it because of the uniqueness of the uniform subsequential limit (due to the pointwise convergence)?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think so yes? Arzela-Ascoli tells us that $\overline{\{f_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$ is compact and not just closed and bounded thanks to equicontinuity, and you can show that any divergent sequence on a compact has at least two adherence values (adherent points? I don't recall the English term). To construct a second one, it suffices to use the negation of the definition of convergence applied on the first adherent point and use sequential compactness on that new subsequence. But due to pointwise convergence, there is only one adherence value, and so $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly.

Comment: But I could be wrong

Comment: I think you are right. I am going to add freely this answer to the duplicate.